# How can I save credentials/session in a iOS web app?

Tags: ios, swift, session, web-applications, credentials

I'm making an iOS web app and I want to save credentials to keep session opened. It is the first time I dev an iOS app

For the moment I only do that:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var KronosWebsite: WKWebView!
    let myUrl = URL(string:"https://mobi.kronos-sport.com")
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url : myUrl!)
        KronosWebsite.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Although by the looks of your question I don't think this is what you looked for the proper way to store credentials is to have a API route in witch you can get an Access Token and a Refresh Token that you will use to interact with an API, even tho you just want to use it as a login. Preferably it should be OAuth (Because is the most secure one) but frankly you can use any that you find proper to your solution.

**Note**: The access and refresh token should be kept in the iOS Keychain as it is the most secure way to store credentials.

> The keychain is the best place to store small secrets, like passwords
>   and cryptographic keys.
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_keychain

**Note**: Alternatively if you must you can store the cookies of that WKWebView like this (But this is not the standard):

```
    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        let dataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
        dataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies({ (cookies) in
            print(cookies)
        })
    } else {
        guard let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies else {
            return
        }
        print(cookies)
    }
```

**More on storing Cookies**:
https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-get-cookies-from-wkwebview-and-uiwebview-in-swift-46e1a072a606

Comment: Thx for your reply Juan Carlos, in the last link they store cookies in "viewWillDisappear" but this function seems not te be call (the prints inside are not visible in the console)

Comment: Yes, but this is just a example. you need to put the code when you need it. the ViewWillDisappear is called when the view is deinit

Comment: But the point of my answer is that you are trying to apply a bad logic in your app, that is not how you should approach it and apple will reject your app if you try it like that

Comment: Also don't post questions as answers!! that is not how stackoverflow work!